# Does OData lib support @odata.nextLink on expanded feeds?

Tags: odata, odatalib

I am using ODataLib to parse OData V4 feeds and entries. One of the OData feeds returns payload with expanded associations that look like this:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"https://myfeed.com/api/data/v8.1/$metadata#accounts(name,Account_Tasks)","value":[
    {
      "@odata.etag":"W/\"596351\"","name":"Account 1","accountid":"5f4c87e4-4952-e611-80dd-c4346bacfc18","Account_Tasks":[

      ],"Account_Tasks@odata.nextLink":"https://myfeed.com/api/data/v8.1/accounts(5f4c87e4-4952-e611-80dd-c4346bacfc18)/Account_Tasks"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note the element "Account_Tasks@odata.nextLink": it provides the link to expanded data. But none of ODataLib classes seems to expose this property.

Is this property exposed by ODataLib or it's not currently supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is supported in ODL, you can find it in

https://github.com/OData/odata.net/blob/ODataV4-6.x/src/Microsoft.OData.Core/ODataFeedBase.cs#L49-L65

```
    public Uri NextPageLink 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nextPageLink;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.DeltaLink != null && value != null)
            {
                throw new ODataException(ODataErrorStrings.ODataFeed_MustNotContainBothNextPageLinkAndDeltaLink);
            }

            this.nextPageLink = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I was using NextPageLink but thought it would be populated properly in this case. But I tested it and it was.